# Gatling script throws an error "type mismatch"

Tags: testing, gatling

I have a problem with my script, I converted it from HAR file and divide it to two separate execs as below. I believe I did it properly (but I'm not 100% sure)

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.{ChainBuilder, ScenarioBuilder}
import io.gatling.commons.validation._

class logingood extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl("https://webapi.wage.iteodev.com")
        .inferHtmlResources()
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36")
        .proxy(Proxy("localhost", 8888).httpsPort(8888))

    val headers_0 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Origin" -> "https://frontend.iteodev.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "cors")

    val headers_1 = Map(
        "Access-Control-Request-Headers" -> "authorization",
        "Access-Control-Request-Method" -> "GET",
        "Origin" -> "https://frontend.iteodev.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "cors")

    val headers_2 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Origin" -> "https://frontend.iteodev.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "cors",
        "authorization" -> "Bearer ${authToken}")
        

    val headers_3 = Map("Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "no-cors")

    val headers_7 = Map(
        "Origin" -> "https://frontend.iteodev.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "cors",
        "content-type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    
    val uri1 = "https://api.wage.iteodev.com/signalr"
    val uri2 = "https://frontend.iteodev.com/static/media/download-app-headline.a2c2b312.svg"

val scn = scenario("logingood")
        .exec(http("request_0")
            .post("/api/oauth/token")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .formParam("username", "test@evxmail.net")
            .formParam("password", "Zaq1@wsx")
            .formParam("grant_type", "password")
            .check(jsonPath("$..access_token").exists.saveAs("authToken"))
            .resources(http("request_1")
            .options("/api/account")
            .headers(headers_1),
            http("request_2")
            .get("/api/account")
            .headers(headers_2),
            http("request_3")
            .get(uri2)
            .headers(headers_3),
            http("request_4")
            .options("/api/conversations/")
            .headers(headers_1),
            http("request_5")
            .get("/api/conversations/")
            .headers(headers_2),
            http("request_6")
            .options("/api/notifications")
            .headers(headers_1)))
           
        .exec(http("request_7")
            .get(uri1 + "/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
            .headers(headers_7),
            http("request_8")
            .get("/api/notifications")
            .headers(headers_2),
            http("request_9")
            .get(uri1 + "/start?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionToken=${MyConnectionToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
            .headers(headers_7))   
                

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

But Gatling throws error

```
GATLING_HOME is set to "C:\Gatling"
JAVA = ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\\bin\java.exe""
10:28:27.322 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - C:\Gatling\user-files\simulations\logingood.scala:74:21: type mismatch;
 found   : io.gatling.http.request.builder.HttpRequestBuilder
 required: io.gatling.core.structure.Execs[_]
            .headers(headers_7),
                    ^
10:28:27.325 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - C:\Gatling\user-files\simulations\logingood.scala:77:21: type mismatch;
 found   : io.gatling.http.request.builder.HttpRequestBuilder
 required: io.gatling.core.structure.Execs[_]
            .headers(headers_2),
                    ^
10:28:27.326 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - C:\Gatling\user-files\simulations\logingood.scala:80:21: type mismatch;
 found   : io.gatling.http.request.builder.HttpRequestBuilder
 required: io.gatling.core.structure.Execs[_]
            .headers(headers_7))
                    ^
10:28:27.371 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - three errors found
10:28:27.378 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation crashed
sbt.internal.inc.CompileFailed: null
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:253)
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:122)
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:95)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:186)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
        at sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:215)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:146)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:120)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:100)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:180)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:98)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:102)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:155)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:92)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:75)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:348)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:301)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:168)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:248

        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:74)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.doCompile(ZincCompiler.scala:210)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.delayedEndpoint$io$gatling$compiler$ZincCompiler$1(ZincCompiler.scala:215)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$delayedInit$body.apply(ZincCompiler.scala:39)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.main(ZincCompiler.scala:39)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler.main(ZincCompiler.scala)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option AggressiveOpts; support was removed in 12.0
Choose a simulation number:
```

What I did wrong? On many examples it looks similar and it works properly. I searched whole internet and didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exec takes either an action, a chain, or a vararg of Execs.

in the block containing request7, you've got an exec where you're trying to pass what looks like a vararg of httpRequrestBuilders.

so instead of

```
.exec(http("request_7")
  .get(uri1 + "/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
  .headers(headers_7),
  http("request_8")
    .get("/api/notifications")
    .headers(headers_2),
  http("request_9")
    .get(uri1 + "/start?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionToken=${MyConnectionToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
    .headers(headers_7))
```

you need to either make them all Execs, or chain them

```
.exec(
  exec(http("request_7")
        .get(uri1 + "/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
        .headers(headers_7)),
  exec(http("request_8")
        .get("/api/notifications")
        .headers(headers_2)),
  exec(http("request_9")
        .get(uri1 + "/start?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionToken=${MyConnectionToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
        .headers(headers_7)))
```

I'm guessing the first exec in your snippet works as all the requests other than the first are done as resources